# How to keep html as html in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using codeMirror to add TryIt Editor as like w3school. The following is working fine:

```
   <form>
       <textarea id="code" name="code">
       HTML CODE
       </textarea>
   </form>
```

But it is not working when I try to replace HTML CODE by the actual content as follows:

```
 <form>
       <textarea id="code" name="code">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
       </textarea>
 </form>
```

I find out the actual reason behind this problem. When I save post in text mode(as following image) all html looks okay. 
[image: code editor with complete html page including head and body tags]

But when I change text mode to visual mode and back to text mode I can see the following:
[image: code editor with only the content that was inside the body]

I also try to wrap all the html with `<pre> </pre>` but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Known issue. You can't really prevent that from happening. Don't use the visual editor and you'll be fine.

Comment: It's not appropriate to have the other content that the visual editor throws away in a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Note issue of tinyMCE on WP.

You can check using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup/

But if you want a preatty clean solution **you can use SHORTCODE to render your HTML structure inside the post safely.**

SHORTCODE DOCS: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

or see this guide (in italian lang but you can translate it).

https://www.targetweb.it/come-creare-shortcode-wordpress-la-guida-completa/